# Snowflake UDF with variable number of inputs

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to pass a variable number of inputs to the following udf in Snowflake.

```
CREATE FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s1 string, s2 string)
  returns string
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(array_construct_compact(s1, s2), '')
  $$
  ;
```

How do you declare variable number of inputs?

Simply using an array does not work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s array)
  returns string
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(array_construct_compact(s), '')
  $$
  ;
  
SELECT concat_ws_athena('a', 'b')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simulate exactly the output of this statement:

```
select array_to_string(array_construct_compact('a', 'b', 'c'), ',');
```

as seen here:

[image]

then your function should look like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s array)
  returns string
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(s, ',')
  $$
  ;
```

and you would call it like this:

```
SELECT concat_ws_athena(['a', 'b', 'c']);
```

not passing 2 separate args but one arary with all args.

Comment: My faul: I should have specified that I would prefer to have a solution which does not need an array as input, i.e. without `[...]`, but more important it should still return a value in case one of the inputs is null. That's why I am using array_constract_compact.

Comment: Variable number of args is not supported so you will probably need that array.

Answer (score 1):

Right now you cannot define a UDF with a variable number of input parameters. You can; however, overload UDFs so you could create a UDF with a variable set of input parameters that way. There would have to be some reasonable limit where you cut off the overloads. For example here the overloads allow 2, 3, or 4 parameters. The number could go much higher.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s1 string, s2 string)
  returns string
  called on null input
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(array_construct_compact(s1, s2), '')
  $$
  ;
  
CREATE or replace FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s1 string, s2 string, s3 string)
  returns string
  called on null input
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(array_construct_compact(s1, s2, s3), '')
  $$
  ;
  
CREATE or replace FUNCTION concat_ws_athena(s1 string, s2 string, s3 string, s4 string)
  returns string
  called on null input
  as 
  $$
  array_to_string(array_construct_compact(s1, s2, s3, s4), '')
  $$
  ;
  
select concat_ws_athena('one','two',null,'three');
```

Also, most but not all Snowflake functions including UDFs will immediately return null if any input parameter is null. To override that behavior on UDFs, you can specify `called on null input` in the definition.